# Sql Server 2012 connection in playframework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I am new to PlayFrameWork can any one tell me hot to do Sql Server connection step by step in playframework 2.4.6 or above.

Comment: You can try one of the templates that come with a little tutorial: https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates#filter:database

Answer (score 0):

Follow [JavaDatabase](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDatabase) If you are working on Java else see [ScalaDatabase](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDatabase). There are examples of MySQl, PostgreSQL etc... Similarly you can configure your drivers and connection details for Sql Server.

Comment: I done but some Cannot connect to database [default] error is showing.